# Verifier function for ActiveDirectoryStrategy does not get called in Passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have this simple enough express application which tries to use Active Directory to authenticate the user. Here is my setup:

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const ActiveDirectoryStrategy = require('passport-activedirectory');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
// AD configuration. Real values omitted.
const config = {
    url: 'ldaps://...',
    baseDN: '...',
    username: '...',
    password: '...'
};

const app = express();

app.use(session({
    secret: 'mysessionsecret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use('ad', new ActiveDirectoryStrategy(
    {
        ldap: config
    },
    (profile, ad, done) => {
        // The problem is here! This never gets called!
        console.log('ActiveDirectoryStrategy activated.');
        done('ActiveDirectoryStrategy not implemented.');
    }
));

// route middleware to ensure user is logged in
const isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) =>
    req.isAuthenticated() ? next() : res.redirect('/auth');

app.get('/', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    res.end('You are logged in.');
});

app.get('/unsecured', (req, res) => {
    res.end('You are not logged in.');
});

app.get('/auth', passport.authenticate('ad', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/unsecured'
}));

app.listen(PORT);
console.log('Listening on port ' + PORT);
```

However, the verifier function I pass for the constructor `ActiveDirectoryStrategy` never gets called. (This is the function with the signature `(profile, ad, done)`).

I am sure that there is no problem with the LDAP configuration, because I can access the active directory just fine with `activedirectory` module with the same parameters:

```
const ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
const ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);

ad.findUser('username', (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
    // prints an object with user's info
});
```

So there must be a problem with my routing. What am I doing wrong? Why is my verifier function not getting called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a misconception I had. I thought the Passport.js's authenticate middleware would perform the NTLM handshake for me. This is not the case. `passport-activedirectory` actually needs something like IISNode to run in front of it in order to perform the NTLM handshake. Since the request does not contain the authentication information,

I settled on using [`express-ntlm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ntlm) middleware as a result. `express-ntlm` gives you the `UserName`, `DomainName`, and `Workstation` properties you can use. But if you want to acquire the full AD profile for some reason, you could setup a custom passport strategy like so:

```
const ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
const CustomStrategy = require('passport-custom');

passport.use('ntlm-ad-backend', new CustomStrategy((req, done) => {
    let username = req.ntlm.UserName;

    AD.findUser(username, (err, profile) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            done(err);
        }

        if (!profile) {
            done(new Error(`User ${req.ntlm.UserName} not found in Active Director.`));
        } else {
            done(null, profile);
        }
    });
}));
```

And then,

```
app.get('/auth', passport.authenticate('ntlm-ad-backend', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/unsecured'
}));
```

Note that you will also have to implement `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser`.